# Not able to ssh into server after setting up cloudflare warp

Tags: cloudflare

On linux server i have installed warp-cli and after `warp-cli register` and later setting `warp-cli set-mode warp+doh` and `warp-cli connect` I lost access to ssh server and i'm no longer able to ssh into that server.

Answer (score 0):

During setup and before running `warp-cli connect` run below cmd.
For example remove 5.5.5.5/32 and use ip address cidr of the  device from which you want to ssh into the server.
`warp-cli add-excluded-route  5.5.5.5/32`

Comment: Not a best solution, but it works, thanks